# how to remove file not found error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic2, angular2-routing

I am trying to get data from server using `http` call .I am getting file not found error .here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/oCxrgxNlCkjVnTrhZGQA?p=preview

```
import { Page, NavController } from 'ionic-angular/index';
import { toDoservice } from '/TodoService'


@Page({
  templateUrl:"home.html",
  providers:[toDoservice]
})
export class HomePage {

  private Todo: Array<Object>;
  constructor(private nav: NavController,private toDoservice:ToDoservice) {
    this.Todo=toDoservice.loadAllTodo();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu have done Various mistakes few of them are as mentioned here :-

- todoService is not decorated with Annotation
- Named of service injection is wrong in your file
- You are importing your file in a wrong way.
- There is no default extension are in the system.config

your Service should be like this :-

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
  http;
  constructor(private http: Http ){
    console.log("hello")
  }

  loadAllTodo(){
    return this.http.get('data.json').map(res => res.json())
  }
}
```

here is working code of your  <kbd>[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3hXlV18ZSNeWwlPygB73?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Use the same casing in class declaration and usage:

```
import { Page, NavController } from 'ionic-angular/index';
import { TodoService } from '/TodoService'


@Page({
  templateUrl:"home.html",
  providers:[TodoService]
})
export class HomePage {

  private Todo: Array<Object>;
  constructor(private nav: NavController,private todoservice:TodoService) {
    this.Todo=todoService.loadAllTodo();
  }
}
```

Comment: He also should subscribe to his `loadAllTodo()` observable. http://plnkr.co/edit/VpiX4szNszinp8VLzewh?p=preview

Comment: Not just that... his `system.config` is completely wrong. It doesn't load because there is no default extension. Changing the import to `import { ToDoservice } from './TodoService.js'`, might help a little...

Comment: I stopped looking after the casing problem. It didn't look to me the Plunker was supposed to actually work.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It was more a support so you could update your answer :D